# How to assign a reference value to a generic property

Tags: c#, generics

I am dealing with generics here but I have this strange situation where I trying to assign an instance of a class to a generic property.

```
class Context<A,T>  where A: Answer<T>
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        A answer; // suppose it have a value;
        answer.context=this; // produce CS00029 error
    }
}

class Answer<T>
{
    Context<Answer<T>,T> context {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What's particularly strange in this situation? Do you mean CS00029 compilation error? Could you show the error message?

Comment: There is no enough information here to answer your question, also this is a fairly nested generic design and fairly suspect

Comment: The statement "where A : Answer<T>" says "when A *derives from* Answer<T>" it does not enforce that they are the same type.

Comment: @TheGeneral I agree. It seems like an overuse of generics.

Comment: Beginners often start going in the wrong direction with generics. They don't know what their data model is, so they make it generic and assume they can decide on the concrete classes later. This is wrong and counterproductive. Generics are more difficult to start with because you have to know every model ahead of time. Instead, build your class only for a single model, like `Answer` only after you have that working should you genericize it to work with more classes.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes I mean the CS00029 compilation error.

Comment: The scenario is that I have a Parent that have children, so I want the parent to inject itself into the child, so the child can notify the parent about something (for example when it is selected). this is a simplified version of the original code, it is a script in Unity, so there are many other restrictions but I am providing here the pure C# portion of the problem. so if there is any suggestion I will be a glade. for example how you inject the parent instance (Context) in the child (Answer) in my situation?

Comment: Instead of *describing* your scenario, could you *show* your scenario? Edit the question and add a more realistic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom interested, I found a solution from someone outside this site, and that is his suggestion:

```
public class Context<A, T>: IContext<A, T> where A : Answer<T>
{
   void SomeMethod()
   {
    A answer = Activator.CreateInstance<A>();
    answer.context = this;
   }
}

public class Answer<T>
{
   public IContext<Answer<T>, T> context { get; set; }
}

public interface IContext<out A, T> {}
```

[The Solution Link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/DevCBeirut/permalink/2211913065592704/)

Comment: you should accept your answer as this solves your problem, also don't hesitate to give a link to the outside source for that solution.

Comment: @SamuelVidal I thought I accepted my answer, did not I?

Comment: ah sorry, I noticed that now, it was a simple click :)